# Customising Word press Admin - Add Post Page functionality to another similar page

Tags: wp-admin

We are Customising Wordpress Admin to build a biz application. WE are using Wordpress as a base to build our application. We used the Add Post page as Add Customer - customised some fields and we posted it to the db using wp_post . Now we want to add two more menu's like Add Vendor, Add Employees ( which should work very similar to the Post Page) and should go to different tables .

We considered Wordpress Admin for Add customer because, we could automatically get Autodraft, commenting, Tag etc., Now we want the same for the other screens that we plan to add.

Now, when we are writing code for the new screens, by default it is getting posted to wp_post table where as it has to go to our new tables that we have designed. We are not sure what is the right approach. Pls advice.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Custom Post Types.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types

If you want to have the usage of non default tables have a look at the pods framework.
http://podscms.org/

Comment: I second Custom Post Types. Pods is great, but if you can use native WP functions then it's worth it. If you need help setting up your custom post types, the Custom Post Type UI plugin is very good.

Answer (score 1):

Hi **@sridhar:**

It sounds like all you need might be Custom Post Types; are you familiar with those? Or do I misunderstand and you have more advanced needs?